# Publish progress?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Why is this not valid according to eclipse:

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            publishProgress(10);  

            if(true){
                //validate with DB
            }else{
                //send to registration screen
            }

            return null;
        }

        //Update Progress       
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            mProgress.setProgress(values[0]);

        }
```

Eclipse is saying this:

```
publishProgress(10);  <<publishProgress(Void) is not acceptable for type publishProgress(Int)
```

However other questions on here show it used in that exact way. Is it a change in the API? I really want to pass publishProgress a string and and int. Is this possible:

```
publishProgress("Starting Validation", 10);
```

TIA

Comment: can you post all your AsyncTask class ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you are declaring the right type in the generic parameters, something like:

```
new AsyncTask()<Void, Integer, Void>{ ...
```

---

[`AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

- **Params:** the type of [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...))'s and [`execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) var-args parameters.
- **Progress:** the type of [`publishProgress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))'s and [`onProgressUpdate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...))'s var-args parameters.
- **Result:** the type of [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...))'s return value, [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result))'s parameter, [`onCancelled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...))'s parameter, and [`get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get())'s return value.

Comment: And if I want to pass a string and an integer to publish progress I can't? It works if I send the int as a string and cast it.

Comment: You can wrapper them together within an instance of a custom class (A class that contains String field and int field).